# How to put a token in field Simplenews -> Subscribtion block -> block message

Tags: tokens

I want to add a token in a field which is used when the simplenews module is installed and configured. There is then a block available for each newsletter. 
In this block the user can fill in his email and push the subsribe button.

I want to display a token in this field:

- Block > Simplenews subscribption block > block message.

(the block title is supporting tokens, but the block message not)

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely there's no off-the-shelf solution here. The block message field is a [variable in the Simplenews module](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/simplenews/simplenews.module/function/simplenews_block_configure/7-1). It's not possible to make variables dynamic; there's no hook to override variable values.

In order to make something like this happen, you'd have to use a combination [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to change the block setting form & [`hook_block_view_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7) to alter the output of the Simplenews block.

Comment: Oke, I never did this so I will try. I guess I have to make a custom module with this methods to override the current behavior.